# How to remove these vertical white lines in PhpStorm 2017.3

Tags: phpstorm

How to remove these vertical white lines in PhpStorm 2017.3?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to? They show you expanded codeblocks (and allow you to see that braces line up), that's useful to see

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the guide on how to post a question here.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207073015-Style-vertical-indent-guides

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to remove foreground on these guides instead of completly disable this feature, since something (either PhpStorm 2017.3 itself or Material Theme plugin) introduced this bug in the latest update.

Go to the `Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> General` and look for the `Guides` section. Uncheck the `Foreground` option on `Visual Guides` or change its color from `EEEEEE` to `32424A`. Hit Apply & Ok.

Now these guides should look the same as in 2017.2.

Answer (score 12):

They're called `Vertical indent guides`

Here's how to turn them off: go to `Settings > Editor > Appearance` and uncheck `Show vertical indent guides`

[image: Where to change them]